# Overflowing int's in OpenMP

Tags: c, overflow, openmp

I'm trying my hand at writing a naive indexOf function. It currently works and gets the right position. However it overflows when counting the number of comparisons. I've tried converting them all to long long ints but it doesnt seem to be making any difference. What can I do to fix this?

```
int hostMatch(long long int *comparisons)
{
    long int i,j,k, lastI;

    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    lastI = textLength-patternLength;
    *comparisons=0;

    int lastIi = lastI+1;
    int position = -1;

    int numberThreads = 1;
    int totalCom = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) num_threads(numberThreads) \
        shared(totalCom, position) \
        private(i,j,k) \
        firstprivate(lastIi,patternLength, textData, patternData)
    for (i=0;i<lastIi;i++)
    {
        if (position != -1)
        {
            // found
        }
        else
        {
            k=i;
            long long int count = 0L;
            for (j=0;j<patternLength;j++)
            {
                count++;
                if (textData[k] == patternData[j])
                {
                    if (j == patternLength - 1)
                    {
                        // found
                        position = i;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                k++;
            }
            #pragma omp critical (totalLock)
            {
                totalCom += count;
            }
        }
    }
    /* END OF PARALLEL SECTION*/
    printf("Total Comparisons = %i\n", totalCom);
    (*comparisons) = totalCom;
    return position;
}
```

Comment: `totalCom` is an `int`; are you sure it isn't the variable that's overflowing?  Also, you don't need `#pragma omp critical` to update `totalCom`; add `reduction(+ : totalCom)` into your `parallel for` header instead.

Comment: thanks, that fixed that issue, but now im having race conditions making the reduction variable be wrong

Comment: You have a race condition on position, but using reduction with totalCom should work fine.

Comment: After many hours I eventually got it working correctly. Part of the problem was impossible expectations that were holding me up

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock : make your post an answer and i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `totalCom` variable is an `int`; that is more likely to be causing the overflow.  Also, you don't need `#pragma omp critical` to update `totalCom`; add `reduction(+ : totalCom)` into your `parallel for` header instead.